# How can I extract a domain name from a string in bash?

Tags: regex, string, bash, parsing

I am writing a bash script to extract a domain out of string of the form:

> ....domain name example.com...

and I want to output *example.com*.

How can I use matching to output this domain name?

Comment: The question is too loosely defined to be answered properly. Try to think of some corner cases and describe how they should be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with GNU `grep`

```
 echo "random words domain name example.com random words" | grep -oP  "domain name \K[^ ]+\.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should better define the pattern of your domain in order to better match it in the string. After that you can use grep to match a regex describing your domain pattern:

```
domain=`echo "....domain name xxx.com..." | grep -om 1 -G "[^ ]*\.com"`
```

Answer (score 2):

Without assuming the domain name ends in ".com"

```
grep -oP '(?<=domain name )\S+'
```

meaning: look for a sequence of non-whitespace characters following the string "domain name "

Answer (score 0):

If the the format is exactly as you say, then this will suffice:

```
awk '/domain name/{print $3}'
```

If the string is stored in a variable, you can use it as follows:

```
awk '/domain name/{print $3}' <<< $string_name
```

If the string is stored in a file with other strings, one per line:

```
awk '/domain name/{print $3}' < input_file > output_file
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm just wondering- in your second example, how does $3 tell awk to output the word that is directly following "domain name"?

Comment: It assumes they are always the first two words.

Comment: ok, is there a way to get the word directly after "domain name" if there are words prior (i.e. "... ... abc def domain name xxx.com....")?

Comment: @user1190650 there is, but it would be easier for everyone if you more explicitly defined the requirements of the problem in your original question.